# Formula to count pair of unique numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations

Recently I came across a problem to count pair of equal number in a sequence.
Assume the sequence consist of $(1,2,2,3,4,3,5,3,)$
The pairs is
 $(2,2)$ 
$(3,3)$ index $4,6$
$(3,3)$ index $4,8$
$(3,3)$ index $6,8$
 So there are $4$ unique pairs in this sequence.
I realized number of unique integers in a sequence has a relation with a unique pairs.
For instance if there are two integer with same value then $1$ pair can be created.
If $3$ unique integers $3$ pairs
If $4$ unique integers $6$ pairs
If $5$ unique integers $10$ pairs
If $6$ unique integers $15$ pairs.
....
Unique pair on $N$ number can be calculated by N-1 + uniqe pair of N-1

Can I come to a formula to count this unique pairs?

Comment: If there are $n$ of a number there are  $(n-1) + (n-2) + .....+ 1 = 1 + 2 + 3 + ....+ (n-1) = \frac {n(n-1)}2$ unique pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of pairs $p(n)$ is $n(n-1)/2$. This is because from $n$ instances you can select the first instance in $n$ ways and then there is $n-1$ instances left from which you can select the second instance in $n-1$ ways. Then you divide by two because it doesn't matter in which order you select the first and second instance.

You see that this coincide with your recursive formula:

$$\begin{align}
n-1 + p(n-1) &= n-1 + {(n-1)(n-2)\over 2} \\
&= {2(n-1) + (n-1)(n-2)\over 2} \\
& = {(n-1)(2 + (n-2))\over 2} \\
&= {n(n-1)\over2} = p(n)
\end{align}$$

Your formula can of course also be motivated directly as you have $p(n-1)$ pairs using only the first $n-1$ instances and when not using only those you must use the last instance and one of the $n-1$ first, this makes $p(n-1)+(n-1)$ pairs. Using the fact that $p(1) = 0 = 1(1-1)/2$ you can together with the above use induction to prove the closed form formula too.